# Faceting by Entity possible?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

Using Hibernate Search, when performing a query against multiple entity classes, is it possible to Facet against the entity class types themselves?

I suppose a way to do this would be to add a static identifier to each class and have that Faceted, but this seems like a cludge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an internal field `_hibernate_class` you could use for that but, if it's not too cumbersome, I would recommend you to add an application level field on your entities:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
public String getClassName() {
    return getClass().getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for the super fast response, that works splendidly.